# Align y-axes of horizontal histogram with series plot in subplots side-by-side

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a line plot (see below).

I would like to add a subplot showing a histogram of the same values that is oriented to the right, such that the y-axis of the line plot matches the value-axis of the histogram.

Any suggestions?

```
dfB2.plot(x='Date', y='Norm')  
plt.axhline(y = y.mean(), color = 'red', linestyle = '--', linewidth = 1)  
plt.axhspan(1, (-1), color='red', alpha=0.10,)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create the subplots with `plt.subplots()` and set `sharey=True`.

In order to make the `df.plot()` and `df.hist()` calls use your subplots, you can pass in the corresponding axes object via the `ax` keyword argument.

For reference:

- https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html
- https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html
- https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html
- https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html

Comment: thanks, I am new to coding and trying to do what you mentioned. 
However, it seems I did not formulate myself correctly. I need the x-axes of the histogram to match the y-axis of the lineplot mentioned earlier....(I edited the post)

Comment: You mean like changing the orientation of the histogram? (you should be able to do it by adding `orientation='horizontal'` keyword arg to the call to `df.hist()`.)